# Git log exclude cherry pick messages for trailers

Tags: git

Say you have this commit log:

```
commit fj9823jf982j3f9j8ydf89j
Author: Bob <bob@example.com>
Date: Today

    subject

    message

    Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
    Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>

commit 978uwf98jwef89jewf98jf98
Author: Alice <alice@example.com>
Date: Today

    subject

    message

    Signed-off-by: Alice <alice@example.com>
    Acked-by: Bob <bob@example.com>

    (cherry picked from commit 7823487234u82398rua)
```

If I'd like to show only the trailers, I'd normally use something akin to `git log --format="%(trailers)"`, which in this case would give me:

```
Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>

(cherry picked from commit 7823487234u82398rua)
```

Thereby only reading the trailers from the first commit, but not from the second, apaprently due to the cherry pick message.

Effectively this means that, if a cherry pick message is present in a commit message, the other trailers can not be read.

Is there a way to have git ignore the cherry pick messages when parsing the trailers?

Comment: The trailers are the stuff before the last blank line, and the `cherry-picked from` is the only thing there, so that's the only part that could *be* a trailer (and then it has the wrong format). I don't think there's currently a way to get Git to "scroll back past" the added cherry-pick line. There probably should be; consider making a request on the Git mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, there really does not seem to be any way for this. Seems like quite an inconsistency for me if a native git-tool can't parse something made natively in Git.

Answer (score 0):

It’s correct that if you have this commit message:

```
commit fj9823jf982j3f9j8ydf89j
Author: Bob <bob@example.com>
Date: Today

    subject

    message

    Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
    Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>

    (cherry picked from commit 7823487234u82398rua)
```

Then this will give no output:

```
cat b.txt | git interpret-trailers --only-trailers
```

And nor will (assuming that `HEAD` is on this commit):

```
git log -1 --format='%s%n%n%b' | git interpret-trailers --only-trailers
```

So that’s the end of the story for all commits which have that
cherry-picked-from line *after* the trailer section.

But note that revision 967dfd4d568c (sequencer: use trailer's trailer
layout, 2016-11-02)[1] taught `git cherry-pick -x` to respect the
trailer section, if it exists:

> Make sequencer use trailer.c's trailer layout definition, as opposed to
> parsing the footer by itself. This makes "commit -s", "cherry-pick -x",
> and "format-patch --signoff" consistent with trailer, allowing
> non-trailer lines and multiple-line trailers in trailer blocks under
> certain conditions, and therefore suppressing the extra newline in those
> cases.

This means that now (I’m on `git version 2.39.2`) if you have this commit:

```
commit fj9823jf982j3f9j8ydf89j
Author: Bob <bob@example.com>
Date: Today

    subject

    message

    Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
    Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>
```

Then a `git cherry-pick -x` will give you a commit which looks like:

```
commit fj9823jf982j3f9j8ydf89j
Author: Bob <bob@example.com>
Date: Today

subject

message

Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>
(cherry picked from commit 78ddce1507732a604913542989c856f15a8d6d88)
```

And with `git interpret-trailers`:

```
$ git log -1 --format='%s%n%n%b' | git interpret-trailers --only-trailers
Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>
```

(Omits the cherry-picked-from line)

With `--format=[…]`:

```
$ git show --format='%(trailers)' @
Signed-off-by: Bob <bob@example.com>
Acked-by: Alice <alice@example.com>
(cherry picked from commit 78ddce1507732a604913542989c856f15a8d6d88)
```

#### Behavior according to the test suite[2]

- `git-cherry-pick -x` will add a blank line before the `-x` line if
  there is no trailer section ([“cherry-pick -x inserts blank line when conforming footer not found”](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.40.0/t/t3511-cherry-pick-x.sh#L176))
- `git cherry-pick -x -s` will add the cherry-pick line and the
  signed-off-by line in that order inside the existing trailer section
  ([“cherry-pick -x -s adds sob when last sob doesnt match
  committer”](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.40.0/t/t3511-cherry-pick-x.sh#L176))
- [“cherry-pick -x treats "(cherry picked from..." line as part of footer”](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.40.0/t/t3511-cherry-pick-x.sh#LL256C21-L256C90)

#### Notes

1. Merged in: 8b0db484e11a (Merge branch
   'jt/use-trailer-api-in-commands', 2016-12-19)
2. All on tag `v2.40.0`